# how to delete a line from a text file in shell programming

Tags: bash, shell, variables, sed, title

Hi I am trying to create a program that will read in the user input of a book title and it's author. and it will search for the record that is recorded in the text file and delete the line that contain the input the user has type in. I tried using sed but I keep showing this error "sed: -e expression #1, char 3: extra characters after command" The following is my codes.

```
echo "Title: "
read title
echo "Author: "
read author

if !( grep -i -q -e "$title" "BookDB.txt" | 
grep -i -q -e "$author" "BookDB.txt" ) ; then   

echo "Error! Book does not exist!"

else 
details="$title:$author"
echo $details
sed -i '/$details/d' "BookDB.txt"

fi
```

Thank you in advance! Sorry if this question appear noob to you and i am very sorry if the question is similar to any question that were asked before because i really couldn't find a code that work in my case.

Comment: Use double quotes: `sed -i "/$details/d" "BookDB.txt"`

Comment: the line is not deleted in the text file even though i use double quotes.

Comment: I did a test on a sample file and it works for me. Make sure data is correct formatted.

Comment: sed is not good for this, as I told someone with [an eerily similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27987545/bash-script-how-do-i-remove-line-word-from-text-file/27988060#27988060) before, because book titles can contain special characters (I suspect this is precisely the problem you ran into). The answer behind the link should help you, you'll only have to replace the space between `$title` and `$author` with a `:`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use like this,

```
 sed -i '/'$details'/d' "BookDB.txt"
```

I hope it will work. Before the `sed` you have to verify that your needed details are placed in the variable which you are using.

Answer (score 0):

You are using single quote instead of double quote in your sed regexp.
Your string $details cannot be expanded, so, sed literraly read '$details' instead of the content of "$details"

```
#!/bin/sh

errorExit() {
    case $1 in
        1) msg="book db file not found";;
        2) msg="Book does not exist!";;
        *) ;;
    esac    
    echo "==> error : $msg"
    exit $1
}

showdb() {
# Show content of the db
    echo "==> Content of $bookdb >"
    cat $bookdb
    echo "<"
}

bookdb="BookDB.txt"

# Create DB
echo "Ubik:Dick" > $bookdb
echo "Apes Planet:Boule" >> $bookdb

# Test db file exists
[ -f $bookdb ] || errorExit 1

# Show content of the db
showdb

# Read the choice
echo -n "Title: "
read title
echo -n "Author: "
read author

# Find and delete data
details="$title:$author"
if !( grep -i -q -e "$details" $bookdb ) ; then   
    errorExit 2
else 
    echo "==> details : $details"
    sed -i -e "/$details/d" $bookdb 
fi

# Show content of the db
showdb

exit 0
```

Output :

```
$ ./test 
==> Content of BookDB.txt >
Ubik:Dick
Apes Planet:Boule
<
Title: Ubik
Author: Dick
==> details : Ubik:Dick
==> Content of BookDB.txt >
Apes Planet:Boule
<
```